# lynx domain shows 404 error when running from localhost

Tags: dns, lynx

I have a strange problem and I don't know where I have to take a look to fix the issue.

I am running the command `lynx https://example.com/index.php` from the server where the website is hosted on and I am getting a `404 Not Found` error.

When running lynx from another server with this URL, or visiting in standard browsers, I see the index.php normally.

Any ideas what could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Does your local box use the same DNS server that other boxes use?

Comment: Or else, does the server have an entry for `example.com` in `/etc/hosts` which interferes with DNS?